# Using postgres JSONB directly

Tags: c++, json, postgresql, jsonb

Is it possible to use JSONB functions in postgres directly (see functions [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/utils/jsonapi.h) and [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/utils/jsonb.h))? By directly I mean creating my own main.cpp and use postgres' JSONB code to do the following 3 operations:

- serialize a plaintext json document (plaintext json -> jsonb)
- access values in the jsonb document
- deserialize a jsonb document (jsonb -> plaintext json)

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    

int main(int, char**) {

    // valid plaintext JSON document
    std::string testJSON = "{ \"id\" : { \"numID\" : 12345, \"strID\" : \"onetwothreefourfive\", \"doubleID\" : 1.2345}, \"hello\" : \"world\", \"age\" : 42, \"cats\" : [ \"first cat\", \"second cat\", \"third cat\" ] }";

   // TODO somehow use postgres JSONB functions to perform the 3 operations:

   // 1. Serialize
   postgresJSONBObject serializedDoc = postgres.serialize(testJSON);

   // 2. Access values
   // access the top-level value associated with key "age" (42 in this case)
   int age = serializedDoc.accessValue("age");

   // 3. Deserialize
   std::string originalJSON = postgres.deserialize(serializedDoc);

   std::cout << originalJson << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link to PostgreSQL code to use parts of it outside PostgreSQL as you seem to want to do. For one, these functions operate on the internal binary representation of `jsonb`, which won't be of much use for you.

Linking to PostgreSQL only makes sense if you are writing a C function that will run inside PostgreSQL.

Comment: I understand that these functions operate on the internal binary representation of jsonb, for my experiments this is exactly what I need. So it is possible to use these functions by linking to postgres? Where can I learn how to do it?

Comment: You can try - linking to PostgreSQL is not different from linking to other executables. But you won't get far: how, for example, do you expect `ereport` to work outside the context of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Do I need `ereport` to work? Could you elaborate why I can't just use the jsonb functions for some quick measurements?

Comment: It is a function that reports errors in PostgreSQL and which can be called from JSON functions. It is just an example. Try for yourself and see how far you get.